# Multivalued fields gone after upgrading to SQL Server from MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that was linked to an MS Access Multivalued field, but after upgrading to SQL Server the link to the table was lost and now I've been unable to get Multivalued fields working.

This is the table that was linked to a Multivalue field

[image]

This is the table it was linked to:

[image]

Adding the relationships in MS Access has not worked, I've used the designer but it didnt help:

[image]

Working in table design didnt help either as it doesnt save for ODBC tables.

Im struggling getting that Memo Field to work with a query that can handle those multivalue fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQLServer doesn't handle multi-value fields. AFAIK, Access is only dbms that does.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix.the existing data? Is it possible to create another layer through a query that could handle multivalued fields?

Comment: A multi-value field just holds pointers to records in a hidden table. You need to build a normal dependent table to replace hidden table. Set up normal relationship with pk/fk fields. Enter records. You could have converted that multi-value field to table before conversion. Exactly how did you do the conversion? You didn't get any error message?

Comment: Cool, thanks heaps, that's what I need. Though I am playing with creating a local table and using that for multiple values and having a VBA procedure to update the odbc tables, but I am struggling with this as I've never worked with muli valued fields in Access, it's a bit of headache.